# Beamer custom colors not working as expected

Tags: beamer, color

I'm trying to set a custom color theme in Beamer, and it's not turning out how I thought it should.

Here's my color theme:

```
\definecolor{NASAred}{RGB}{252, 61, 33}
\definecolor{NASAblue}{RGB}{11, 61, 145}

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=NASAblue, fg=white} % title block on first slide
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=NASAblue, fg=white} %right-hand side of bottom
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=NASAred, fg=white} % center bottom
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=NASAblue,fg=white} % left bottom
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=NASAred,fg=white} %
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=NASAblue} % box headings


\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=NASAblue} % TOC sections
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=NASAred,fg=white} %
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=NASAblue, bg=white} %
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=NASAblue,bg=white} %
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=NASAblue} %
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=NASAblue,bg=white} %
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{NASAblue}$\bullet$} %
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\color{NASAblue}\scriptsize{$\bullet$}}%
```

And here's my results:

[image: full image]

Zoomed in:

[image]

Neither of the colors (which I got the RGB for from [the official NASA style guide](https://sservi.nasa.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/NASA_Style_Guide_v2.1.pdf)) look like the colors in the actual meatball (or like the samples in the style guide, when I put them next to each other). In particular, the blue looks too dark and the red looks too orange. I've tested this on three different monitors, so now I suspect that there are some darkening or lightening rules built into the custom colors in Beamer, instead of just using them as-is, but I can't find any documentation about it.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at p. 12 of the design guide, the colours in the "Full color insignia" seems to be darker then in the logo on your slides - or on the logos which one finds on the internet.

### Workaround:

I took the `.svg` of the meatball logo from Wikipedia and opened it with inkscape. For example for the blue area, I see the following values:

[image]

Either use these values for defining the beamer colours or take the values from the style guide and adjust the image accordingly.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{infolines}

\definecolor{NASAred}{RGB}{238, 41, 61}
\definecolor{NASAblue}{RGB}{26, 93, 173}

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=NASAblue, fg=white} % title block on first slide
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=NASAblue, fg=white} %right-hand side of bottom
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=NASAred, fg=white} % center bottom
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=NASAblue,fg=white} % left bottom
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=NASAred,fg=white} %
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=NASAblue} % box headings


\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=NASAblue} % TOC sections
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=NASAred,fg=white} %
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=NASAblue, bg=white} %
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=NASAblue,bg=white} %
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=NASAblue} %
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=NASAblue,bg=white} %
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{NASAblue}$\bullet$} %
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\color{NASAblue}\scriptsize{$\bullet$}}%

\title{Text}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{2000px-NASA_logo}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Logo file taken from https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/NASA_logo.svg)

Comment: Thank you! I am not allowed to alter the logo, and I can't install Inkscape, so I guess I'll have to live with it for now :-/

Comment: @MissMonicaE If you can't alter the logo, why don't you try with `\definecolor{NASAred}{RGB}{238, 41, 61}
\definecolor{NASAblue}{RGB}{26, 93, 173}`?